# Devise how to allow logged user to sign up another user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to be able to sign up new user even if I am logged in.

Right now if I click "sign up" while logged in, registration form will not show up. Instead the error message will say "you are already signed in".

I want to allow user(admin) to add new users to the system.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Create a `UsersController` and **authenticate the user as admin**. Then in `new` and `create` actions of the controller, you can put your user creation logic. And copy the content of `views/devise/registration/new.html.erb` file to `views/users/new.html.erb`.

**Expanded answer:**

You can create a role table if there are more than two roles to manage. That will make it easy to manage them. May be you can you cancan and rolify gems to manage scope for a role if needed.

And if there are only two roles (Admin and other/normal users) then you can add a boolean column `admin` in the `users table`.

Comment: can you please expand your answer?

Comment: @aldo.roman.nurena what kind of expansion do you want here? I think it is pretty clear for someone who has worked with devise and rails.

Comment: Yes, just like that. Not clear for a starters and this should be clear .

Comment: Well, for example, what does "authenticate the user as admin" mean.  Do we need to add a new table or column to the database to indicate adminship?

Comment: @DavidGrayson.. It depends on the requirement and definitely on you. :) You can use a different table for managing Roles or add a string column called role in user table or if there are only two roles then you can add a boolean column admin in user table.